# Upgrading to SvelteKit 2 it throws with "Cannot find module 'graphql-request/build/esm/types' or its corresponding type declarations.ts (2307)"

Tags: typescript, sveltekit, graphql-request

#### Describe the bug

Upgrading today from `"@sveltejs/kit": "1.30.0"` to `"@sveltejs/kit": "2.0.0"` and deleting `node_modules` and `package-lock.json`, if I run `npm install` on typescript check I get:

[image]

`Cannot find module 'graphql-request/build/esm/types' or its corresponding type declarations.ts (2307)`

Why?

Maybe some issue with package.json `exports`?

```json
"exports": {
    ".": {
      "require": {
        "types": "./build/cjs/index.d.ts",
        "default": "./build/cjs/index.js"
      },
      "import": {
        "types": "./build/esm/index.d.ts",
        "default": "./build/esm/index.js"
      }
    }
  },
  "types": "./build/esm/index.d.ts",
```

#### Severity

blocking an upgrade